# Цвет фона и стилизация приложения

Tags: android, color

Здравствуйте.
Хочу указать цвет фона, но андроид не принимает код, хоть и отображает его.

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">#ffffff</item>
```

> error: Error: Color types not allowed (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '#ffffff').

И так с любым цветом.
Подскажите, как это исправить.

Еще подскажите, где можно поподробнее почитать про свойства дизайна приложения.
Я делаю по примеру ([Стилизация приложений часть первая](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133307/)),
но интересует, как убирать/добавлять элементы меню, вроде кнопки меню, перекрашивать цвет полоски с наименованием приложения в верхней части экрана и т. д.

Comment: @Xetag, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно в values/colors.xml добавить:

```
    <color name="background_color">#ffffff</color>
```

и в файле values/styles.xml указать ссылку на цвет:

```
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам же черным по белому написали, что error: **Error: Color types not allowed (at 'android:windowBackground' with value '#ffffff').**, что переводится, как *Цвета не разрешены в этом параметре*. Еще, если прочитать [офф документацию](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), то станет ясно, что

> (Note that the color needs to supplied
> as a separate resource here because
> the android:windowBackground attribute
> only supports a reference to another
> resource; unlike
> android:colorBackground, it can not be
> given a color literal.)

Это значит, что нужно определить ресурс с цветом в роде `@color/custom_theme_color`